# backbone _.chain(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use _chain, but I got:

> _.chain(...).getUniq is not a function
>   My code:

```
var Offer = Document.extend({
    default: {
        name: null,
    },

    set: function (attributes, options) {
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

 var Offers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    getUniq: function () {
        return _.uniq(this.pluck("name'));
    },
    model: Offer
});

var offers = new Offers;
offers.add(offer1);
_.chain(offers).getUniq()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `getUniq` is not an underscore function.

The `_.chain()` function returns an underscoreJS object:

```
_.chain = function(obj) {
    var instance = _(obj);
    instance._chain = true;
    return instance;
  };
```